# Passing a pointer to a function causing the 2nd call to crash the program

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I'm testing out a compression library and it's working fine for me, but I needed a wrapper function to avoid some unneeded parameters. The library call looks as follows:

```
typedef int WINAPI OodleLZ_CompressFunc(
        uint32_t codec, char *src_buf, uint64_t src_len, char *dst_buf, int64_t level,
        void *opts, int64_t offs);
typedef int WINAPI OodleLZ_DecompressFunc(
        char *src_buf, int64_t src_len, char *dst_buf, uint64_t dst_size, int fuzz, int crc, int verbose,
        uint8_t *dst_base, size_t e, void *cb, void *cb_ctx, void *scratch, size_t scratch_size, int threadPhase
    );
```

my assigned functions are the following:

```
OodleLZ_CompressFunc* oodl_compress;
OodleLZ_DecompressFunc* oodl_decompress;
```

When I call the decompression function then the compression function using `oodl_compress` and `oodl_decompress` everything works fine. However when I create a wrapper for the functions, compression stops working.

Working Scenario:

```
// Predefined data, compressed_size, decompressed_size
char *dec_data = new char [decompressed_size];
oodl_decompress(data, compressed_size, dec_data, decompressed_size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

char *com_data = new char [decompressed_size + 0x10000];
oodl_compress(c_type, dec_data, decompressed_size, com_data, c_level, 0, 0); //c_type and c_level are constants (7 in this case)
```

When I create the wrapper `Decompress`, calling `Decompress` works but calling `oodl_compress` no longer works.
`Decompress`:

```
int Decompress(char* src_buf, int64_t src_len, char* dst_buf, uint64_t dst_len)
{
    oodl_decompress(src_buf, src_len, dst_buf, dst_len, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
// Predefined data, compressed_size, decompressed_size
char *dec_data = new char [decompressed_size];
Decompress(data, compressed_size, dec_data, decompressed_size);

char *com_data = new char [decompressed_size + 0x10000];
oodl_compress(c_type, dec_data, decompressed_size, com_data, c_level, 0, 0); //c_type and c_level are constants (7 in this case)
```

What happens is that when calling `oodl_compress` in the 2nd scenario, the program would freeze for 1 second and then quit, without giving any error. I have code afterwards that would just `fout<<` into a file, and I can see that in the 2nd scenario the file is empty, where in the first scenario the file is recompressed, representing the original state of the data.

I don't seem to figure out where my issue is, as I'm simply repassing the variables into another function that just fills the remaining parameters with 0 instead of having it in main. I know this is not necessary, but understanding what is wrong in this instance will help me avoid such a scenario in the future.

Comment: I join you in not seeing anything wrong outright, but there could be an earlier mistake that finally gets exposed by the function.

Comment: @user4581301 The previous code is `ifstream fin("file.bin", ios::binary); char data[100]; fin.read(data, 100);` and the next code is `ofstream fout("file.dec", ios::binary); for (int i = 0; i < decompressed_data; i++) fout<<dec_data[i];`

Comment: Where (and how) are you assigning actual function addresses to your function pointers?

Comment: @AdrianMole in a class I called Oodle, inside a function called resolve_functions(). The problem isn't with the function assignment since it's working in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue but I don't know "Why" it's the issue.

In my Decompression function:

```
void Decompress(char* src_buf, int64_t src_len, char* dst_buf, uint64_t dst_len)
{
    int data_size = oodl_decompress(src_buf, src_len, dst_buf, dst_len, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (data_size < 0)
    {
        throw std::string("Decompression Error");
    }
}
```

and in my Compression Function:

```
int64_t Compress(char *src_buf, uint64_t src_len, char* dst_buf)
{
    int64_t data_len;
    data_len = oodl_compress(compression_type, src_buf, src_len, dst_buf, compression_level, 0, 0);
    return data_len;
}
```

The culprit in both cases is the `data_len` and `data_size` variables. For some reason, whenever I remove them, the code works fine. I'm guessing it's something to do with the the stack/heap? (I'm not really good with terminology).
Any insight on this and a proposed fix/alternative is appreciated!
For now I just swapped both functions to be like this:

```
int64_t Compress(char *src_buf, uint64_t src_len, char* dst_buf)
{
    return oodl_compress(compression_type, src_buf, src_len, dst_buf, compression_level, 0, 0);
}

void Decompress(char* src_buf, int64_t src_len, char* dst_buf, uint64_t dst_len)
{
    oodl_decompress(src_buf, src_len, dst_buf, dst_len, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```